# Graph occurrences by category over time in r and display sums

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, aggregate

I've been trying to learn r and have been experimenting with some data. Here is a sampling of the data:

```
IBDClass date      month  year
A       2014-04-01   04   2014
A       2014-05-22   05   2014
B       2014-01-10   01   2014
B       2014-02-24   02   2015
B       2015-09-17   09   2015
C       2015-11-01   11   2015
```

I've been able to get [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc035.png) by splitting up the date into month/year columns and then graphing that. I'm sure there is a better method to do this. I'd like to also have a label for the sum of occurrences per month. Hope someone can help!

```
ggplot(report, aes(x=month, fill=IBDClass))
+geom_bar(position="stack", binwidth=1)
+facet_wrap(~year, ncol=1, scales="free_x")
+geom_text(stat="bin", aes(label = ..count..), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1.5, position="stack")
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What's wrong with your current result?

Comment: I'd like to add total sum above each bar.

Comment: @Heroka did my previous comments help clarify the questions? Still trying to figure this out.